# terraform - azurerm. Difference between Standard_LRS and StandardSSD_LRS

Tags: azure-rm, azure-disk

What is the difference between terraform Standard_LRS and StandardSSD_LRS?
Terraform documentation points only, that you can chose one of those 2 but doesn't precise what is the difference.
Is Standard_LRS an HHD disk? Or can it be SSD disk also?

Comment: Thank you @RahulKumarShaw-MT for great explanation

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Irina you are guessing correct.

Microsoft now offers three types of storage for your Azure Virtual Machines and they include `Standard HDD Storage,` `Standard SSD Storage`, and `Premium SSD Storage`. Standard HDD Storage is based on the traditional hard disk model, Standard SSD and Premium SSD Storage are both based on Solid State Storage but offer different performance characteristics.

**'Standard_HDD' disks will show 'Standard_LRS' in the StorageAccountType property, 'Standard SSD' will show 'StandardSSD_LRS', and a Premium SSD disk will show 'Premium_LRS' in that property.**